# What is the inverse of the cyclic shift operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-information

I have given the cyclic shift operator $X(x) \in \mathbf{R}^{d \times d}$, the generalized pauli operator, for a qudit system. This operator is defined by the action it takes on an arbitary ket vector $\left| j \rangle \right. \in \mathbf{R}^d$ with: $$X(x) \left| j \rangle \right. = \left| x \oplus j \rangle \right..$$ Thereby $\oplus$ describes the cyclic addition operator defined by: $$x \oplus j = (x + j) \text{mod}(d).$$ Now I'm supposed to show that the inverse of this operator equals $X(-x)$. My approach is to look at how this operator acts on an arbitary ket vector. This should be something like: $$X(x) \left| j \rangle \right. = \left| x \oplus j \rangle \right. \langle j \left| j \rangle \right. = \left| x \oplus j \rangle \right..$$
So the inverse of this operator should act as:
$$ X^{-1}(x) \left| j \rangle \right. = (\left| x \oplus j \rangle \right. \langle j \left| \right.)^{-1} \left| j \rangle \right. = \left| j \rangle \right. \langle x \oplus j \left| \right. j\rangle.$$
But at this point I have no clue how to show that this expression equals $X(-x)$.

Edit:

With the correction by *By Symmetry* I've tried to invert the operator directly. So my new approach is:

$$X(x)=\sum_j \left| \right. x \oplus j \rangle \langle j \left. \right|.$$

So the inverse operator is given by:

\begin{align} 
X^{-1}(x) 
&= \left( \sum_j \left| \right. x \oplus j \rangle \langle j \left. \right| \right)^{-1} \\
&= \sum_j \left| \right. j \rangle \langle x \oplus j \left. \right| \\
&= \sum_j X^{-1}(-x) X(-x) \left| \right. j \rangle \langle x \oplus j \left. \right| \\
&= \sum_j X^{-1}(-x) \left| \right. -x \oplus j \rangle \langle x \oplus j \left. \right| \\
&= \sum_j \left| \right. -x \oplus j \rangle X(-x) \langle x \oplus j \left. \right| \\
&= \sum_j \left| \right. -x \oplus j \rangle \langle x-x \oplus j \left. \right| \\
&= \sum_j \left| \right. -x \oplus j \rangle \langle j \left. \right| = X(-x).
\end{align}

I hope I got this right.

Comment: If $d\ne 1$ the operator $|x\oplus j\rangle \langle j | $ does not have an inverse (although the operator $\sum_j |x\oplus j\rangle \langle j | $ does) so your approach will, at the very least require some reworking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inverse operators are unique, so it is sufficent to show that $X(-x)$ is *an* inverse to show that it is *the* inverse. With that in mind
\begin{align}
X(-x)X(x)|j\rangle &= X(-x)|x\oplus j\rangle\\
&= |-x \oplus (x\oplus j)\rangle\\
&= |(-x \oplus x)\oplus j\rangle\\
&= |0 \oplus j\rangle\\
&= |j\rangle
\end{align}
so $X(-x)X(x)$ acts trivially on any basis vector $|j\rangle$. By linearity this extends to an arbitrary state $|\psi\rangle$, so $X(-x)X(x) = 1$. Therefore $X(-x) = X^{-1}(x)$